# Scipy optimize.minimize a complex function with 2 real variables and 1 argument

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, complex-numbers, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm looking to minimize a non linear complex function with 2 variables and 1 constant. I found a question for how to minimize a complex function and i think it work(?) I haven't tried it yet, because i want to firs solve the multiple variable one argument problem.

For example a super simple real function:

```
def function(param):
    x, y, a = param
    return(x**2 + y**2 + a*x)
```

I can make a minimization with respect of the 3 parameters, however not with respect to 2 variables 1 constant. If i do

```
minimize(function, [2,4,5])
```

it works fine.

I found this question where someone asked to to something similar to me, but the answer doesn't work for me, the answer says to do:

```
def function(x, y, a):
    return(x**2 + y**2 + a*x)
minimize(function, 2, 4 args=5)
```

but this gives me errors, even just minimizing with the 3 in this way `minimize(function, 2, 4, 5)` gives me a lot of lines of errors, and in this way `minimize(function, (2,4,5))` is gives `>missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'a'.`.

Next for the complex thing, in the answer i looked it said to separate the function into 2 real functions, solve them with minimize, then fuse both results into one. But i am not sure i understood so if someone can help me there. The function is a complex function (real and imaginary part) but the inputs (2 variables 1 constant) are real.

Maybe there is a package that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by separating the arguments that you want to vary during the minimization process from the others. Something like:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def function(t, a):
    x, y = t
    return(x**2 + y**2 + a*x)

res = minimize(function, (2, 4), args=5)
```

If you don't want to change the function signature and internals you can use a wrapper:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def function(x, y, a):
    return(x**2 + y**2 + a*x)

def wrapper(f, a):
    def newfunc(t):
        return f(*t, a)
    return newfunc

res = minimize(wrapper(function, 5), (2, 4))
```

Comment: Oh that works, thanks. If i want to add more constants i'll should add them as a vector instead of the a?.

Comment: You don't have to add them as vectors, they can be passed to the function through `args`. It's just the variable part that needs to be grouped.

Comment: Ok, nice thank. And i did the wrapper function, and i think is even better.